# Diazo XSLT and external document only work with a hardcoded path to the document

Tags: plone, diazo

So far the only way to load my external document is to hardcode the path. I'd like to be able to use a relative path or variable.

I've created a Diazo rule which transforms content from an external page (called 'footer-columns') and places it in my themed pages.

**Version A - This version works (note the hardcoded path):**

```
 <replace css:theme-children=".footer-menu-row">
     <xsl:for-each
       select="document('http://example.com/footer-columns')//*/dl[contains(@class,'portletStaticText')]/dd"
     ><div class="w-col w-col-3">
           <xsl:copy-of select="." />
     </div>
     </xsl:for-each>
      </replace>
```

**Version B - This version does not work:**

```
 <replace css:theme-children=".footer-menu-row">
     <xsl:for-each
       select="document('{$portal_url}/footer-columns')//*/dl[contains(@class,'portletStaticText')]/dd"
     ><div class="w-col w-col-3">
           <xsl:copy-of select="." />
     </div>
     </xsl:for-each>
      </replace>
```

**Version C - absolute path does not work (in fact it returns an error):**

```
 <replace css:theme-children=".footer-menu-row">
     <xsl:for-each
       select="document('/footer-columns')//*/dl[contains(@class,'portletStaticText')]/dd"
     ><div class="w-col w-col-3">
           <xsl:copy-of select="." />
     </div>
     </xsl:for-each>
      </replace>
```

**Version D - relative path does not work (in fact it returns an error):**

```
 <replace css:theme-children=".footer-menu-row">
     <xsl:for-each
       select="document('footer-columns')//*/dl[contains(@class,'portletStaticText')]/dd"
     ><div class="w-col w-col-3">
           <xsl:copy-of select="." />
     </div>
     </xsl:for-each>
      </replace>
```

For version C and D I get the same error:

> AttributeError: 'PersistentResourceDirectory' object has no attribute
>   'getPhysicalPath'

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a nodeset to the `document()` method. Diazo already sets a variable named `diazo-base-document` with the proper nodeset.

Try:

```
select="document('footer-columns', $diazo-base-document)//*/dl[contains(@class,'portletStaticText')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify `href="/footer-columns"` on the `replace` tag?